# I can't get my program to test: "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, bufferedreader

When I try and run the program this is what the computer returns:

> First_Name    Last_Name   Test1       Test2       Test3       Test4       Test5       Average     Grade
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
> tests.Tests.main(Tests.java:132) C:\Users\Michael
> Jr\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java
> returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

```
package tests;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
/**
 *
 * @author Michael 
 */
public class Tests {

   private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private int[] scores;
 
    public Tests(String entry)
    {
        String[] data=entry.split(" ");
        scores=new int[data.length-2];
        this.setFname(data[0]);
        this.setLname(data[1]);
        for(int i=2;i<data.length;i++)
        {
            scores[i-2]=Integer.parseInt(data[i]);
        }
    }
    public int[] getScores() {
        return scores;
    }
    public void setScores(int[] scores) {
        this.scores = scores;
    }
 
    public static String getAverageScore(int[] a)
    {
        int sum=0;
        for(int e:a)
        {
            sum+=e;
        }
        return new DecimalFormat("##.##").format((double)sum/(double)a.length);
    }
 
    public static void showAverage(List<Tests> e)
    {
        for(Tests s:e)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
    public String getGrade()
    {
        double d=Double.parseDouble(Tests.getAverageScore(scores));
        if(d<=100 && d>=90)
        {
            return "A";
        }
        else if(d<90 && d>=80)
        {
            return "B";
        }
        else if(d<80 && d>=70)
        {
            return "C";
        }
        else if(d<70 && d>=60)
        {
            return "D";
        }
        else
        {
            return "F";
        }
    }
    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }
    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }
    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }
    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return getFname()+"\t\t"+getLname()+"\t\t"+scores[0]+"\t\t"+scores[1]+"\t\t"+scores[2]+"\t\t"+scores[3]+"\t\t"+scores[4]+"\t\t"+getAverageScore(scores)+"\t\t"+getGrade();
    }
 
    public static ArrayList<Tests> read(String path)
    {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
 
            String sCurrentLine;
            ArrayList<Tests> ar=new ArrayList<Tests>();
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Michael Jr\\Desktop\\ch9_Ex13Data.txt"));
 
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                ar.add(new Tests(sCurrentLine));
            }
            return ar;
 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
 
        } 
        finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static void main(String[] a)
    {
        ArrayList<Tests> ar=read("E:/score.txt");
        System.out.println("First_Name\tLast_Name\tTest1\t\tTest2\t\tTest3\t\tTest4\t\tTest5\t\tAverage\t\tGrade");
        for(Tests e:ar)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is on line 132. what is the code there?

Comment: You *did* get your program to compile. Otherwise you could never have got a runtime exception, which, err, happens at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the result of your read function:

```
public static void main(String[] a)
    {
        ArrayList<Tests> ar=read("E:/score.txt");
        if (ar != null){  
            System.out.println("First_Name\tLast_Name\tTest1\t\tTest2\t\tTest3\t\tTest4 \t\tTest5\t\tAverage\t\tGrade");
            for(Tests e:ar)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Could not read file");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Or make the read method always return a list instead of null

Comment: this fixed the null problem but the file can't be read now? and i have the location in just right.

Comment: You are passing in a value of "E:/score.txt" as path, but then reading from a hard-coded path of "C:\\Users\\Michael Jr\\Desktop\\ch9_Ex13Data.txt" - which file do you want to read? Maybe this is a permissions issue?

Answer (score 0):

are you verifying the `try` statement?, the read function is returning 'Null' value. I think this problem is when you are reading the file.

```
String sCurrentLine;
        ArrayList<Tests> ar=new ArrayList<Tests>();
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Michael Jr\\Desktop\\ch9_Ex13Data.txt"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            ar.add(new Tests(sCurrentLine));
        }
        return ar;
```

if you are able to share the file, I will verify this code right!

Comment: the contents of the file the program is trying to read are below.

Comment: Jack Johnson 85 83 77 91 76
Lisa Aniston 80 90 95 93 48
Andy Cooper 78 81 11 90 73
Ravi Gupta 92 83 30 69 87
Bonny Blair 23 45 96 38 59
Danny Clark 60 85 45 39 67
Samantha Kennedy 77 31 52 74 83
Robin Bronson 93 94 89 77 97
Sheila Sunny 79 85 28 93 82
Kiran Smith 85 72 49 75 63

@Evinton

Comment: When you are working with decimalformat, firstly, verify the computer number format  in your laptop or desktop computery.
 the mistake is here `DecimalFormat("##.##").format((double)sum/(double)a.length);`
change '.' to ',' `DecimalFormat("##,##").format((double)sum/(double)a.length);`

@mikeg4523

Comment: after fixing the DecimalFormat("##,##").format((double)sum/(double)a.length) it still gives me the same output

Comment: I think the problem is the read function now that i ve been toying with it the code works until that point. I just don't understand why.

Comment: i don't know where to look other than that.@Evinton Antonio Cordoba Mosque